# CSV python code: multiplying variables

Tags: python, csv, multiplication

**So far this is my code:**

```
with open("products.txt", "r") as productsFile:
    GTIN8 = input("Enter your GTIN-8 product code: ")
    productsFileReader = csv.reader(productsFile)
    for row in productsFileReader:
        for field in row:
            if field == GTIN8:
                print (row) #displays the product details
                price1= (row[4])
                quantity= (int(input("how many of these would you like to purchase?:")))
                totalprice= quantity * price1 #multiplies quantity by price
                print (totalprice)
```

I am currently trying to multiply the variable of 'price1' by the 'quantity' which will be entered by the user. price1 is from a row in a csv txt.file I have created.

Every time I run the program, the multiplied price (for example if it were £2.50) displays as "£2.50£2.50£2.50".

**How can I make my python code *multiply* variables together?**

thanks

### ^Thankyou to all who has helped: now it works howver I have another issue...**

```
productsFileReader = csv.reader(productsFile)
for row in productsFileReader:
    for field in row:
        if field == GTIN8:
            item1= print (row)#displays the product details
            price1= (row[4])
            quantity= (int(input("how many of these would you like to purchase?:")))
            totalprice= quantity * float(price1.replace("£", "")) #multiplies quantity by price
            print (totalprice)
print("Thankyou, your item will cost: "+totalprice)
```

now when I try to display the price at the end of my program an error of:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

from my understanding, I need to make the float (what I changed before) into an integer so that my code can display a price. but how?
*many thanks once again*

Comment: `price1` is a _string_. Multiplying a string by an integer repeats it `n` times. For example `'dup'*5 == dupdupdupdupdup`.

Comment: Regarding your edit: You need to change the float into a _string_, not an integer. If you convert it to an integer, you'll lose the decimal part. You can do this with `str(totalprice)`, but you probably also want to do currency formatting, which is a whole other problem... Try looking around on the internet for people that have already asked this question, instead of asking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

price1 is a string, and you are multiplying it by an int, which will just result in the string being concatenated n times.

```
>>> animal = "cat"
>>> animal*4
'catcatcatcat'
```

You need to convert price1 to a float before it can be multiplied by an int to get the expected result.  This is done through the float function.  However, if you call float on your price string you will get a ValueError because of the £ symbol, so you must first remove it using str.replace like so:

```
>>> price = "£2.50"
>>> price = price.replace("£", "")
>>> float(price)
2.5
```

Integrating this into your code:

```
price1 = row[4]
quantity = int(input("how many of these would you like to purchase?:"))
totalprice = quantity * float(price1.replace("£", "")) # multiplies quantity by price
```

Comment: As anupsabraham pointed out, you could also remove the £ symbol using price1.lstrip("£") or even by slicing the string like price1[1:]   Slicing is probably fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to multiply a string (`price`) with an integer(`quantity`). That is why you are getting an output like this. You need to convert the data you are taking from the file.

```
price1 = float(row[4].lstrip('£'))
```